# how to connect a cellphone with computer by incoming connection?

Tags: .net, networking, mobile, mobile-phones

hi
Is it possible to connect a cellphone with computer by incoming connection or something like?
i dont want to use wireless,bluetooth and etc,i want to conect a mobile phone with computer by their modems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by Cable connection , but it depends to your cell phone.Some cell phone dosen't have this capability.

Comment: Ok,But without any connection between cell phone and computer how you can connect them?It seems you want connect cell phone to computer without any connection.It is impossible.

Comment: i want to use their modems,we can do this on 2 pc by incoming connection.

Comment: Yes, but this 2 pc must have a cable connection , Wireless connection or.. and then you can connect them, if you connect cell to pc by cable then you can use it as modem or connection.